# How to use Inno Setup to update a database using .sql script

Tags: sql, inno-setup

I'd like to compile a setup that will connect to a remote database using the credentials provided by the user, then install few db components using .sql script.

Is that possible using Inno Setup?

More details:

I'd like to have a custom form, asking the user to enter the database address and credentials, then run a command that will execute an sql script that will update the remote database server.

If the update is successful - complete the installation with success.

This is rather general question - I have a lot of customized setups that should connect to different servers/run different scripts - the idea is to build a generic form that will provide this functionality.

Comment: It surely is possible, but without further information it's hard to give a meaningful answer. What is your question? Did you already try to do it? What database? Please clarify...

Comment: well, the idea is to have a generic form - details above ..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think you can have a completely generic form, as for different servers you may need either a single connection string, or a server name and an (optional) port; for some servers you will use system authentication, for others a user name password tuple.

Having said that I will give you a small demo Inno script that asks for server name and port, user name and password, then makes a few tests, then executes an application that is extracted (by code) to the temp directory and will be deleted by the installer. You can use this as a starting point for your scripts. Having a few of such snippets, and including them in your scripts as necessary will probably be all you need:

```
[Setup]
AppID=DBUpdateTest
AppName=Test
AppVerName=Test 0.1
AppPublisher=My Company, Inc.
DefaultDirName={pf}\Test
DefaultGroupName=Test
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
PrivilegesRequired=none

[Files]
Source: "isql.exe"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
Source: "update_V42.sql"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Code]
var
  DBPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  DBPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpReady,
    'Database Connection Information', 'Which database is to be updated?',
    'Please specify the server and the connection credentials, then click Next.');
  DBPage.Add('Server:', False);
  DBPage.Add('Port:', False);
  DBPage.Add('User name:', False);
  DBPage.Add('Password:', True);

  DBPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Server', '');
  DBPage.Values[1] := GetPreviousData('Port', '');
  DBPage.Values[2] := GetPreviousData('UserName', '');
  DBPage.Values[3] := GetPreviousData('Password', '');
end;

procedure RegisterPreviousData(PreviousDataKey: Integer);
begin
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Server', DBPage.Values[0]);
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Port', DBPage.Values[1]);
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'UserName', DBPage.Values[2]);
  SetPreviousData(PreviousDataKey, 'Password', DBPage.Values[3]);
end;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
var
  ResultCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = DBPage.ID then begin
    if DBPage.Values[0] = '' then begin
      MsgBox('You must enter the server name or address.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end else if DBPage.Values[2] = '' then begin
      MsgBox('You must enter the user name.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end else if DBPage.Values[3] = '' then begin
      MsgBox('You must enter the user password.', mbError, MB_OK);
      Result := False;
    end else begin
      ExtractTemporaryFile('isql.exe');
      ExtractTemporaryFile('update_V42.sql');
      if Exec(ExpandConstant('{tmp}') + '\isql.exe', '--user ' + DBPage.Values[2]
        + ' --password ' + DBPage.Values[3] + ' --database ' + DBPage.Values[0]
        + ':foo --script update_V42.sql', '',
        SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
      then begin
        // check ResultCode and set Result accordingly
        Result := ResultCode = 0;
      end else begin
        MsgBox('Database update failed:'#10#10 + SysErrorMessage(ResultCode),
          mbError, MB_OK);
        Result := False;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Beware: I haven't fully tested this, so there may be more code necessary to properly clean everything up. Error handling is definitely missing!

Comment: Or you can use a COM interface [`like ADODB`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12296113/960757) for instance.

Comment: @TLama: You can of course if your database server provides that kind of interface. Above example however was taken from similar code I use for Firebird.

Comment: Used this code for MSSQL 2008, but instead of isql used sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: @nikolai.serdiuk Did it work out of the box, or you made added adjustments to the one you made