# Inno setup: Pass parameter (user input) to sql using ADO

Tags: ado, inno-setup

I am using ADO to [connect to SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260493/connect-to-sql-2008-using-inno-setup) in my inno setup, which is working fine. I am also executing few scripts to create database,users,schemas etc. 
I am getting the Database name from the user and i want the script to create the database based on the user input, hence inside the script i'm using $(DBNAME) to get the value as parameter. I tried using CreateParameter, which isn't working fine,[Im not sure if im using it correctly]  is there any other option to achieve this?

My inno code:

```
if LoadStringFromFile(ExpandConstant('{app}')+ '\SQLScripts\SCRIPT-1_CREATE_DB.sql', SQLQuery) then
      begin
      ADOCommand.CommandText := SQLQuery;
      ADOParameter := ADOCommand.CreateParameter('DBNAME', adChar,adparaminput,30);
      ADOParameter.Value := 'Dynadbnew';
      ADOCommand.Parameters.Append (ADOParameter);
      ADOCommand.Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
     end;
```

Below is my sample .sql script

```
USE [master]

CREATE DATABASE $(DBNAME) ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'WMSFBASEDB_Data', FILENAME = N'C:\MDF\$(DBNAME).MDF' , SIZE = 420352KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'WMSFBASEDB_Log', FILENAME = N'C:\MDF\$(DBNAME)_1.LDF' , SIZE = 16824KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%)

ALTER DATABASE $(DBNAME) ADD FILEGROUP [FG_HIS1]

ALTER DATABASE $(DBNAME) ADD FILEGROUP [FG_HIS2]

ALTER DATABASE $(DBNAME) SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid that into such block of commands is not possible to pass parameters (when you'd execute this block command by command then it should be easy though). But maybe I'm wrong, at least I'll try. A dirty workaround - you're loading this command block into your InnoSetup script, so what about string replace the `$(DBNAME)` token with your desired value there ? It would be easier than implementing ADO parameters, in fact it's one liner `StringChangeEx(SQLQuery, '$(DBNAME)', 'MyDatabase', True);` called before assigning to the `ADOCommand.CommandText`. But it's just a dirty workaround...

Comment: That's correct, SQL Server does not permit variables anywhere that it's expecting to see an identifier -- this includes database, table, and field names.  You can only use variables in places where it is expecting an expression.  TLama's suggestion of using out-of-db string replacements is usually the best way to go -- but bear in mind that if this comes from a user-provided string you'll need to sanitise it yourself (check for invalid characters, use [] quoting to prevent keyword clashes, etc).

Comment: @TLama, I am using as u said, by string replace, its working fine as of now. :) so will continue to use this.

Comment: @Miral, thanks for suggestion.will do the check.