# ADO.net SQL Server commands failing on x86 Windows Server 2008

Tags: deployment, oledb, inno-setup, adodb

I am deploying project with developer-targeted setup using Inno Setup. I've wrote some code to make some actions that are a bit too custom for the original Inno Setup.
One of such actions was connecting to and running SQL files, thanks to StackOverflow users  [I've found some code for doing so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260493/connect-to-sql-2008-using-inno-setup/12296113#12296113). The problem is that whenever I try deploying the project on a new Windows Server 2008 machine (x86), I'm getting such cryptic error on every sql command apart from the first one:

> "Not enough storage space is available to complete this operation ProgID: ADODB.Connection"

So. The first command fires and works, next stop with error. If I'd run the code again, some of the commands might work, but at some point, the installer would hung. **The problem does not exists on windows XP I am writing it on**.

I use the code linked above for every SQL command I run (new ole object ADODB.Connection, new command, execute... end) - I don't make the second query for results of insert (as it's there just for showing purpose).

Any thoughts what can be happening here or how can I make a workaround?

Comment: Have you tried doing multiple Executes on a single Connection?  The server might be throttling you because you're not supposed to rapid-fire connect.  Although usually it's not quite so picky as to object to a second connection.

Comment: Yes, I've tried - results were similar.

Comment: I've connected all of the sql queries into one and... it works. I'd like to know why it didn't want to work with many commands on vista or windows server and did on windows xp.

Comment: Just check this link, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182423