# Inno setup: connect to sql using windows authentication

Tags: inno-setup

can anyone tell me how to connect to SQL 2008 using windows authentication thru inno? Currently I'm using [ado connection to connect to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260493/connect-to-sql-2008-using-inno-setup#) from inno, the user needs windows authentication option too. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough to remove the credential attributes from your connection string (`User Id` and `Password`) when we are talking about the example you've linked in your question and include one of the following:

1. `Integrated Security=SSPI;`
2. `Trusted_Connection=True;`

This answer is based just on [`this topic`](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sqlconnection-connection-string.aspx#trusted), I haven't tested it.

***Update:***

I don't know if that's what you want to do, but I'll post it here. The following script creates a custom page with radio buttons letting user choose authentication mode and optionally fill the credentials.

***Important:***

There is no protection against SQL injection for those credential fields!

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  LT_WindowsAuthentication = 0;
  LT_SQLServerAuthentication = 1;
var
  LoginType: Integer;
  UsernameEdit: TNewEdit;
  UsernameLabel: TLabel;
  PasswordEdit: TNewEdit;
  PasswordLabel: TLabel;

procedure OnLoginTypeChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  EditColor: TColor;
  LabelColor: TColor;
begin
  LoginType := TNewRadioButton(Sender).Tag;
  UsernameEdit.Enabled := LoginType = LT_SQLServerAuthentication;
  PasswordEdit.Enabled := LoginType = LT_SQLServerAuthentication;
  case LoginType of
    LT_WindowsAuthentication: 
    begin 
      EditColor := clBtnFace;
      LabelColor := clGray;
    end;
    LT_SQLServerAuthentication: 
    begin
      EditColor := clWindow;
      LabelColor := clBlack;
    end;
  end;
  UsernameEdit.Color := EditColor;  
  PasswordEdit.Color := EditColor;
  UsernameLabel.Font.Color := LabelColor;
  PasswordLabel.Font.Color := LabelColor;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  LoginPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  LoginPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'DB Login', 'Choose a login type to continue...');
  with TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm) do
  begin
    Parent := LoginPage.Surface;
    Left := 0;
    Top := 0;
    Width := LoginPage.Surface.ClientWidth;
    Checked := True;
    Tag := 0;
    Caption := 'Windows authentication';
    OnClick := @OnLoginTypeChange;    
  end;
  with TNewRadioButton.Create(WizardForm) do
  begin
    Parent := LoginPage.Surface;
    Left := 0;
    Top := 20;
    Width := LoginPage.Surface.ClientWidth;
    Checked := False;
    Tag := 1;
    Caption := 'SQL Server authentication';
    OnClick := @OnLoginTypeChange;
  end;

  UsernameLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with UsernameLabel do
  begin
    Parent := LoginPage.Surface;    
    Left := 12;
    Top := 44;
    Width := 200;
    Font.Color := clGray;
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
    Caption := 'Username';
  end;
  UsernameEdit := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  with UsernameEdit do
  begin
    Parent := LoginPage.Surface;    
    Left := 12;
    Top := UsernameLabel.Top + UsernameLabel.Height + 6;
    Width := 200;
    Color := clBtnFace;
    Enabled := False;    
  end;

  PasswordLabel := TLabel.Create(WizardForm);
  with PasswordLabel do
  begin
    Parent := LoginPage.Surface;    
    Left := 12;
    Top := UsernameEdit.Top + UsernameEdit.Height + 6;
    Width := 200;
    Font.Color := clGray;
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
    Caption := 'Password';
  end;
  PasswordEdit := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  with PasswordEdit do
  begin
    Parent := LoginPage.Surface;
    Left := 12;
    Top := PasswordLabel.Top + PasswordLabel.Height + 6;
    Width := 200;
    Color := clBtnFace;
    Enabled := False;    
    PasswordChar := '*';
  end;
end;

// and in your connection event then use
case LoginType of
  LT_WindowsAuthentication: 
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +                    // provider
      'Data Source=Default\SQLSERVER;' +        // server name
      'Initial Catalog=Northwind;' +            // default database
      'Integrated Security=SSPI;';              // trusted connection      
  LT_SQLServerAuthentication:
    ADOConnection.ConnectionString := 
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +                    // provider
      'Data Source=Default\SQLSERVER;' +        // server name
      'Initial Catalog=Northwind;' +            // default database
      'User Id=' + UsernameEdit.Text + ';' +    // user name
      'Password=' + PasswordEdit.Text + ';';    // password
end;
```

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to provide user credentials too? so that can connect to remote sql server.

Comment: You mean offer to user login either by credentials or by Windows authentication ?

Comment: I mean, the windows credentials thru ado connection. Say the SQL server is on some remote machine and the user needs to connect to it with a windows credentials of that machine, as the current windows user may be different than the one in SQL remote server machine.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, what you mean. You can connect to a remote machine using local user's Windows credentials if you configure the server side that way. And those credentials should be used for connection when you follow the way from this post.

Comment: yes agreed, but if the remote server login is of different user, still will be able to connect? say, I need to connect to SQL server on ur machine, then i would require your windows credentials than my local machine's right?

Comment: Assuming I'm an SQL server, you know about me only where I am (server location) and you're saying that you're trusted for me (and you're giving me your Windows credentials to authenticate). Then I have to be configured to allow [`Windows authentication`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx) in a global way and I must have you added as a user that can login through Windows authentication. The connection to me must be secured and trusted of course, otherwise you're out of luck.

Comment: Got your point. Thanks :) However the answer was useful to me .

Comment: Is there an option to give a name/caption for text boxes? I know there is an option to give "Text:='Username'", which comes inside the box & the user need to remove before they enter their value, hence thought to give a caption like in CreateInputQueryPage