# How to log ADO connection's execute statements

Tags: ado, inno-setup

I am using ado connection to [connect to sql 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260493/connect-to-sql-2008-using-inno-setup) from inno, and i would like to know if we can log the details into a file so that can capture the errors thrown by sql.

Note: Thru ado connection I am not just executing select querys, i am using ado connection to execute set of statements to create database, procedure, tables etc.

Comment: Do you mean how to log ADO provider specific errors ? All the errors that occur during your scripts execution may be catched by the exception handler, but you can get from the connection object provider specific (more detailed) error objects. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For logging a database provider specific errors, use the [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) collection of the ADO [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. How to log these errors to a file, shows the following pseudo-script:

```
procedure ConnectButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;  
  ADOError: Variant;
  ADOConnection: Variant;  
  ErrorLog: TStringList;
begin
  ErrorLog := TStringList.Create;
  try    
    try
      ADOConnection := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Connection');
      // open the connection and work with your ADO objects using this
      // connection object; the following "except" block is the common
      // error handler for all those ADO objects
    except
      // InnoSetup scripting doesn't support access to the "Exception" 
      // object class, so now you need to distinguish, what caused the
      // error (if ADO or something else); for this is here checked if
      // the ADO connection object is created and if so, if its Errors
      // collection is empty; if it's not, or the Errors collection is
      // empty, then the exception was caused by something else than a
      // database provider
      if VarIsEmpty(ADOConnection) or (ADOConnection.Errors.Count = 0) then
        MsgBox(GetExceptionMessage, mbCriticalError, MB_OK)
      else
        // the Errors collection of the ADO connection object contains
        // at least one Error object, but there might be more of them,
        // so iterate the collection and for every single Error object
        // add the line to the logging string list
        for I := 0 to ADOConnection.Errors.Count - 1 do
        begin
          ADOError := ADOConnection.Errors.Item(I);
          ErrorLog.Add(
            'Error no.: ' + IntToStr(ADOError.Number) + '; ' +
            'Source: ' + ADOError.Source + '; ' +
            'Description: ' + ADOError.Description          
          );
        end;      
    end;
  finally
    ErrorLog.SaveToFile('c:\LogFile.txt');
    ErrorLog.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks @Tlama, i will try it and let you know soon.

Comment: the code does capturing the error, but its not poping up any, due to this the user will not know if there is any issue.

Comment: Sure, because you wanted to log them. It's just a pseudocode, showing how to log only DB provider specific errors (and showing only all non DB provider specific ones to users). If you want to show also DB provider specific errors to users, use a `MsgBox`, but be careful to not to be annoying, since there might be more than one error in the `Errors` collection.

Comment: oh ok @Tlama, will try to see what i can do :)