# Inno Setup Executing a large sql script file during installation

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup

I am trying to connect with SQL server and execute a script file while installing the setup. I managed to execute a simple script without `GO` statement in it.

**Question:** Is there a way to pass (skip) the `GO` word and execute the script?

```
 ADOConnection.ConnectionString :=
      'Provider=SQLOLEDB;' +  
        'Data Source=' + ServerEdit.Text + ';' +
        'User Id=' + UsernameEdit.Text + ';' +
        'Password=' + PasswordEdit.Text + ';' + 
        'Trusted_Connection=no;';
  end;

 ADOConnection.Open;
try

  ADOCommand := CreateOleObject('ADODB.Command');
  ADOCommand.ActiveConnection := ADOConnection;
  ScriptPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Script2.sql');

  if LoadStringFromFile(ScriptPath, ssquery) then
  begin
   StringChangeEx(ssquery, 'GO', '', True);
    SQLQuery :=  ssquery
    ADOCommand.CommandText := SQLQuery;
    ADOCommand.Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText or adExecuteNoRecords);
    Result := True;
  end;
finally
  ADOConnection.Close;
  end;
```

The Script2.sql

```
USE northwind3

GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Customers By City]    Script Date: 5/25/2016 8:35:45 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customers By City]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@param1 NVARCHAR(20))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT CustomerID, ContactName, CompanyName, City from Customers as c where c.City=@param1
END


GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Customers Count By Region]    Script Date: 5/25/2016 8:35:45 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Customers Count By Region]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (@param1 NVARCHAR(15))
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @count int
    SELECT @count = COUNT(*)FROM Customers WHERE Customers.Region = @Param1
    RETURN @count
END
```

NOTE: I am using ADOB for the connection in similar way [TLama's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/960757/tlama) answer to [How to connect to MS SQL Server using InnoSetup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260493/850848) Except in my case I have to include `GO` in my script.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Just include the `go` in the `.sql` file.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl The problem is 'GO' is a batch terminator and using it in ADOCommand.Execute() is incorrect.  Throws an exception like "Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.".

Comment: Isn't it the same as executing multiple separate SQL scripts in sequence?

Comment: Yeah,  but i have a lot of procedures and views. Making a separate sql script for all of them isn't an option for me.

Comment: The *"**pass (skip)*** the GO" and *"I **have to include** GO in my script."* seems contradictory to me. Do you mean that you have scripts with `go` and you cannot modify them, but you actually do not care about the `go` and it's ok to execute the scripts as if the `go` was not there?

Comment: *"isn't an option for me"* - why?

Comment: When i say pass, i meant executing the script but skipping the 'go' and its not an option for me because i have too many Views and Procedures around 2k. I can't make a separate .sql script file for all of them.

Comment: So just load the script file to memory and remove the `go` statements before you execute the script over ADO. Added to the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112855/discussion-between-abdul-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the SQL script to separate script files long the `go` statements and execute them individually in a sequence.

---

If that's not an option, you have to use API/tool that supports the `go` statement, i.e. the `sqlcmd` tool, instead of the ADO.

---

Or just load the script file and remove the `go` statements before you execute the script over ADO.

You can use [`StringChange` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_stringchange).

Comment: Sorry i was away from work.  I tried the StringChange function it didn't work throws  'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch. I think sqlcmd is my only option. I know nothing about it, if there is an example or a link  on how to use it on innosetup. thanks

Comment: Can you append an example script to your question along with your `StringChange` code?

Comment: Cannot you even remove all those `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` and `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON`?

Comment: The problem is not the `SET ANSI_NULLS ON`  its the `GO`.  i removed them and tried. Tried removing the `go`, With out the go statement it throws the above exception. Lets continue the discussion here please http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112855/discussion-between-abdul-and-martin-prikryl