# Inno SetUp: Check if Sql Intance is SqlExpress

Tags: sql-server, inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup for installation.
I want to run Addscript.sql if Sql intance is SqlExpress and I want to run AlterScript.sql if Sql intance is SqlServer.

Can you please help me how to check if Sql intance is SqlExpress in Inno SetUp?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Which gives an output like:

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8 
    May 31 2018 16:32:45 
    Copyright (C) 2018 Microsoft Corporation
```

I don't have a SQLExpress instance running here, so I don't know the exact output for that but you can try to run it. After that make a if statement for the expected sql express output.

This example tells you how to combine it with your inno-setup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12296113/1408786

Comment: See the url I mentioned, this tells you exactly how to execute a query in inno-setup. What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Thanks @user1408786 your answer helped me.