# Visual Studio publish a Database project

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I created in visual Studio a Database-Project and a WindowsForm Application C# that relates to the local Database-Project.

Right now everything is working fine and I want to publish my zpplication to a PC without Visual Studio.

I can create the `setup.exe` from my WindowsForm without any problems and run it on my PC, where my local SQL Server exists.

If I transfer the `setup.exe` to the second PC and run it, it is not working, because the SQL Server is missing.

How can I publish or copy my Database-Project/SQL-Server to the second PC without Visual Studio needed?

I do not need the data in the database necessarily. I just need the structure of the database to run my Application.

I thought about bringing both projects in one, but I have lot of DataSets and manually Connectionstrings in my WindowsForm. I do not know how I can change my dataconnection without starting from scratch.

The solution I have in mind is to transfer both projects separately with a USB. First install the Server and afterwards my WindowsForm without Visual Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are so many people asking "how do I put my project, that uses a database, on another machine?" all of a sudden? Is there some major online university imminent deadline for handing in a work item about databases ?

Comment: There are two solutions 1) Clear the database and include an emtpy mdf file with empty tables 2) You want to save the schema of the database which is the structure without any data.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-schema-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: If you just need `structure of the database`, you can try to use [Sqlite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli). It can be included in the project as a file

Answer (score 1):

I feel you have to follow the basic steps.

1. Use any installer to install your project and as a prerequisite, you can install SQL Server on the client computer.
2. I suggest having a look at Inno Setup, its very easy and there are many samples available to install SQL Server on the client computer as a part of your application setup.

A very nice example of dependency installer with Inno Setup is at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-Installer-for-InnoSetup

3. Generate full SQL Script of the database from your development environment using SQL Management Studio and you can run this script on end-user/client computer using SQL connection through your installer.

Here is an example of how you can do this with Inno Setup. [How to use Inno Setup to update a database using .sql script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171199/how-to-use-inno-setup-to-update-a-database-using-sql-script)